# mysql delete query by SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I want to delete the records returned by this query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS tag, COUNT( tag ) AS count
FROM _tags
GROUP BY tag
HAVING count = 1
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `tag` is `_tags`' primary key:

```
DELETE _tags.* FROM _tags
JOIN ( 
    SELECT tag FROM _tags GROUP BY tag HAVING COUNT(tag) = 1 LIMIT 100
) AS subq USING (tag)
```

Not sure what you mean by "delete by SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS". If you just want to know how many records match your condition ignoring the `LIMIT` clause, then you should run a `SELECT` first.

Comment: run and get this error message:   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN ( SELECT tag, COUNT(tag) FROM _tag GROUP BY tag HAVING COUNT(tag) = ' at line 2

Comment: you know i have 430 pages of tags in my website i want to delete tags which number of publications is :1 my sqk query return this tag and now i want to delete them